# UWP File Picker FileTypeFilter Exception

Tags: c#, uwp, filepicker, filefilter

I have a very simple question, but is there a way while using a FilePicker in a UWP app to specify a file filter such as "All files except .exe and .pdf"?

I know to specify **only** a filter for these files you would use:

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");  
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
```

Or to include all files you would use:

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

So is there a way to specify * **except** .exe and .pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's much more common to only accept a few types or, genuinely, anything.
If you really can accept anything apart from .exe and .pdf then accept anything and then validate after the file is selected.